# What is wrong with my Model and Controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

For the life of me I cannot understand why I am receiving errors with my install of CodeIgniter and this current MVC set up.

The error I see is

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Login::users_model() in /var/www/application/controllers/login.php on line 17

**Controller** application/controllers/login.php

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {

    $data = '';

    $this->load->model('users_model');

    $data['testing'] = $this->users_model()->test_user();

    $this->load->view('home',$data);


    }
}
```

**Model** application/models/users_model.php

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_model extends CI_Model {

  function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }


  function test_user() {
      return 'Test User #1';
  }



}
```

**View** application/views/home.php

```
echo $testing;
```

Comment: `users_model` without the `()`

Comment: Load your model in constructor and remove () while calling function of model

Comment: anything answer is working for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for function bracket with model name

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {

    $data = '';

    $this->load->model('users_model');

    $data['testing'] = $this->users_model->test_user();

    $this->load->view('home',$data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$data['testing'] = $this->users_model()->test_user();` with `$data['testing'] = $this->users_model->test_user();` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Simply load your model inside the constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('users_model');
}
```

Then simply call the relevant functions inside any controller functions like this.

```
public function index()
{

$data = '';

$data['testing'] =  $this-> users_model-> test_user();

$this->load->view('home',$data);
}
```